# Check for current page in a js file to render out different partials

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have implemented a favorites system into my rails app, which works on the individual show page for the Tracks model. This is all handled through the Favorites controller, so I am attempting to use the same js file for both index and show pages. This is what I have tried so far. It works if I only have the show page material, the javascript doesn't work at all for either if I do it this way.

favorite.js.erb

```
<% if current_page?(track_path(@track)) %>
  $("#favorites").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('tracks/favorites')) %>");
<% else %>
  $("#favorites").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('albums/favorites')) %>");
<% end %>
```

the partial for tracks/favorites

```
<% if user_signed_in? && current_user.favorited?(@track) %>
  <%= link_to image_tag('icons/heart_full.svg', width: 20), track_unfavorite_path(@track), method: :post, remote: true %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to image_tag('icons/heart_empty.svg', width: 20), track_favorite_path(@track), method: :post, remote: true %>
<% end %>
```

the partial for albums/favorites

```
  <% if user_signed_in? && current_user.favorited?(track) %>
    <%= link_to image_tag('icons/heart_full.svg', width: 20), track_unfavorite_path(track), 
    method: :post, remote: true %>&nbsp;<%= pluralize( track.favorites.count, 'favorite' ) %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to image_tag('icons/heart_empty.svg', width: 20), track_favorite_path(track), 
    method: :post, remote: true %>&nbsp;<%= pluralize( track.favorites.count, 'favorite' ) %>
  <% end %>
```

Passing the instance variable as the parameter works for the show page, but trying to do it for the loop results is what is confusing me.

favorites_controller.rb

```
class FavoritesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    before_action :find_track

  def favorite
    @track.favorites.where(user_id: current_user.id).first_or_create
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @track }
      format.js
    end
  end 

  def unfavorite
    @track.favorites.where(user_id: current_user.id).destroy_all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @track }
      format.js
    end
  end

    private
    def find_track
        @track = Track.find(params[:track_id])
    end
end
```

The view for Track show page is simple:

```
<div id="favorites">
  <%= render 'tracks/favorites' %>
</div>
```

The view for the loop on the index page:

```
<% @tracks.each do |track| %>
    <div class="track_thumbnail">
        <% if track.avatar? %>
            <%= link_to image_tag(track.avatar.url), track_path(track), width: 100, title: track.title %>
        <% else %>
            <%= link_to image_tag(track.user.avatar.url), track_path(track), width: 100, title: track.title %>
        <% end %>
        <%= link_to track.user.username, user_path(track.user) %>
    </div>
    <div class="track_overview">
        <h2><%= link_to track.title, track_path(track) %><% if track.explicit == "explicit" %>&nbsp;(explicit)<% end %></h2>
        <p class="description"><%= truncate(track.description, length: 160) %></p>
        <div class="icons_container">
          <div id="favorites">
            <%= render 'albums/favorites', :track => track %>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I saw different variable `@track` and `track`  on `tracks/favorites` and `albums/favorites`

Comment: Yes, because the albums version I am rendering the partial each time in the loop. I'll update the code to show the view.

Comment: Updated the code.